# Export Checksum

Tags: export, checksum

Is it possible to export a checksum?  This is an essential step to using a range of external services - alternate bulk email(Mail Chimp),  QR code creation for name tags, etc.

But checksum does not appear as a field for exporting.  Is there an alternate method for either generating the checksum or exporting it?

Answer (score 1):

A checksum isn't store anywhere until it is *generated*. So there is no way to export them (like from a report), you should generate them first. The checksum is apparently made up from the contact hash and some things like an expiry date.

More here
[How do contact hashes work, and how do I keep them secure?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/381/how-do-contact-hashes-work-and-how-do-i-keep-them-secure)

Answer (score 1):

MattWire has done an extension https://github.com/mattwire/uk.co.mjwconsult.checksum which indicates you can send a checksum via an external mail system - but you would be needing to copy/paste a different checksum for each and every contact you are sending to

Answer (score 0):

There is an API which checks a checksum specifically from online pages, that might help you? You can find it here : https://civicrm.org/extensions/validate-checksum-api